# trigger onkeypress event in OverlayTrigger react-bootstrap component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a html input wrapped with overlayTrigger component and the trigger property sat to 'focus'.
can i set the trigger to a different action like onkeypress? I need to display my toolTip after key press. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use overlay trigger for tooltip like this,

```
  <OverlayTrigger
          placement="right-start"
          delay={{ show: 250, hide: 400 }}
          overlay={
            <Tooltip id="ReasonForFlag">
              'your message'
            </Tooltip>
          }>
          {checkbox}
        </OverlayTrigger>
```

Comment: Yes i know, but do you have any idea how can i trigger the tooptip to show on keypress event? in the overlayTrigger there is only 3 options  'click' + 'focus' + 'hover' to trigger it but i need to use onkeypress.